# Is it possible to refer to a cell by name or label?

Tags: google-sheets

If I put some data in a given cell, can I refer to that cell by an arbitrary name or label?  For example, if I put the value '0.454' in cell B2, can I assign it a name like 'pounds_per_kg'.  I'd like to be able to use 'pounds_per_kg' for calculations performed on other cells, rather than '$B$2' or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a named range by selecting **Data** > **Named ranges** from the menu. You can create a one-cell named range and use the range name in your calculations without any problems.

The solution is described in detail [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/63175?hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

i hope this will help you go to your Sheet and in menu section go to **Format -> Conditinal Formating** here you can give validation what you want?